# 'for' loop explanation request

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

I recently started learning python.
So I wrote some small code, this code asks for 2 sizes of lists, creates 2 lists with random integers from 0-9 and then spits out the intersection between two lists.

The last "for" loop - I had trouble with it because at first my "intersection" list had repetitions, then I looked up for an answer and got what I have now, it works, however I don't know why. My problem is grasping how "for i in l1 and in l2" works? 
I know that "for i in range(k)" is going through the numbers 0-k but this strange for loop with the "and" operator just puzzles me.

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
C = []
s1 = int(input("Your 1st list size->"))
s2 = int(input("Your 2nd list size->"))
for i in range(s1):
    from random import randint
    k = (randint(0,9))
    l1.append(k)
print("First List ->" , l1)
for i in range(s2):
    from random import randint
    k = (randint(0,9))
    l2.append(k)
print("Second List ->" , l2)
for i in l1 and l2:
    if i in l1 and l2:
        C.append(i)

print("Intersection ->" , C)
```

Please let me know if there is another place to submit such questions(if here is not for suitable).

Comment: "for i in l1 and l2" - that's optimistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is very misleading, so it's understandable that you're confused.  The following code fragment is the issue:

```
for i in l1 and l2:
    if i in l1 and l2:
        C.append(i)
```

This is effectively equivalent to the following:

```
for i in l2:
    if i in l1:
        C.append(i)
```

In the `for` statement, the grouping is `for i in (l1 and l2)`.  In other words, `l1 and l2` is evaluated, and the resulting list is used.  If `l1` is non-empty, then this is just `l2`.  If `l1` is empty, then it's an empty list `[]`, but this works since in that case the intersection must be empty.

In the `if` statement, the grouping is `if (i in l1) and l2`.  If `l2` is non-empty, then this will be effectively true if `i in l1` is true.  If `l2` is empty, this will always be effectively false, but again, this works since in that case the intersection must be empty.

Note that the loop body can be sped up by creating a set for `l1`.  This will make the membership test essentially constant-time rather than linear in the length of `l1`:

```
s1 = set(l1)
for i in l2:
    if i in s1:
        C.append(i)
```

You can also use a list comprehension to obtain equivalent results, assigning to `C` rather than appending to it:

```
s1 = set(l1)
C = [i for i in l2 if i in s1]
```

Comment: The alternative indeed makes a lot more intuitive sense !

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand how `for` loop works we need to examine what's the result `l1 and l2`. In Python non-empty container will evaluate `True` in boolean context and empty container is respectively `False`:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1])
True
```

Then `and` operator will return first parameter in case it's `False` in boolean context and second in case that first parameter evaluates as `True`:

```
>>> [] and [1]
[]
>>> [2] and [1]
[1]
```

Given the information above we then know that `for i in l1 and l2:` results items in `l2` being iterated in case `l1` is non-empty. Respectively loop won't run even single time if `l1` is empty.

Within the loop `if i in l1 and l2:` evaluates `True` in case `i` can be found from `l1` (and `l2` is not empty but the execution wouldn't end up here if `l2` wouldn't contain single item). Since the loop only iterates over items on `l2` and checks if `i` is present in `l1` it will generate the intersection. Note that you'd get the same result with following code:

```
for i in l2:
    if i in l1:
        C.append(i)
```

You could check the `set` in order to make generating the intersection much simpler:

```
>>> set([1,2,3]) & set([4,5,1])
set([1])
```

Note that since sets are collection of unique items the results would be different in case that `l2` contains multiple copies of same item:

```
Your 1st list size->4
Your 2nd list size->4
First List -> [8, 8, 0, 2]
Second List -> [0, 4, 0, 3]
Intersection -> [0, 0]

>>> set([8, 8, 0, 2]) & set([0, 4, 0, 3])
set([0])
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming both lists are non empty:

```
l1 and l2 == l2
```

hence what you are writing is:

```
for i in l2:
   if i in l1 and l2:
        c.append(i)
```

This makes sense.

I would look into python sets if I were you:

```
s1 = set(l1); s2 = set(l2)
intersection = list(s1.intersection(s2))
```

Comment: Sorry, I just started and I dont know what sets are (I know from mathematics for sure ).. But still thanks for the answer!

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if you just started, but in future the method you are using will be slow in comparison to using the set intersection methods. Look them up if you have time. Or you can just remember that they exist if you are ever trying to do something like this again